# collision detect with irregular shape

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

hello i am  making game in which i am making shape like diamond 
using ccdrawpoly method .

and i have sprit object with ball.png
and i want to detect collision with this polygon (diamond  shape) .

in short  ball do not go through inside the shape please help me.......

Answer (score 1):

Your diamond can likely be separated into a set of more basic shapes that can be used to do the intersection math more easily (triangles, squares)

Comment: my shape is not image type but i have make shape using opengl.

Answer (score 0):

you can find collision using

if (CGRectIntersectsRect(imgView1.frame, imgView3.frame)){

```
//Collision true
```

} else {

```
    //Collision false
```

}

hope its help you